# extra /// when pulling info from database

Tags: php

i am using a funstion to insert data into the database

so here is where it inserts

i am inserting this

```
<div class="widget" id="recentcomments"><h2>Blog</h2></div>

update_option("head-text", mysql_real_escape_string($head_text));
```

so it inserts into the database and when i save and pull it back out like below.

```
<input type="text" name="head-text" id="head-text" class="regular-text" value="<?php echo htmlentities($head_text, ENT_QUOTES); ?>"/>
```

i get the following.

```
<div class=\\\"widget\\\" id=\\\"recentcomments\\\"><h2>Blog</h2></div>
```

loads off \\\\

sorry for the vag question before.

Comment: I enjoy detailed questions like these. Seriously. What's the code?

Comment: Didn't you try `addslashes()` and `stripslashes()`?

Comment: It's likely to be magic_quotes_gpc directive being on, which adds slashes that you're doubling with mysql_real_escape_string.

Answer (score 1):

According to the manual [mysql_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php)

> If magic_quotes_gpc is enabled, first
>   apply stripslashes() to the data.
>   Using this function on data which has
>   already been escaped will escape the
>   data twice.

You can go for a function like this (in case you don't want to use prepared statements)

```
function safe($input)
{
    if (get_magic_quotes_gpc())
    {
        $input   = stripslashes($input);
        $escaped = mysql_real_escape_string($input);
    }
    else 
    {
        $escaped = mysql_real_escape_string($input);
    }

    return $escaped;
}
```

There's no need to call stripslashes() on output if SQL escaping is done properly

Answer (score 0):

You have your data escaped **twice** before it gets inserted into database.

You have to find what causing this, and turn off excessive escaping.

It could be `magic_quotes_gpc` setting.
In this case you have to turn off this setting in the PHP configuration.
And add a code that checks `get_magic_quotes_gpc()` result and strips slashes from all superglobal arrays.

if magic quote are certainly turned on,
It could be also just mysql_real_escape_string/addslashes being called twice in your code. You have to search your code for this and get rid of one which is called earlier than anaother

Answer (score -1):

Thanks for the replies got it working with the following.

```
<?php echo htmlentities(stripslashes($head_text)); ?>
```

needed them both

Comment: you do not understand. You have to remove eccessive escaping from the code that adds data to the database instead.